# General strict weak order comparison predicate template function

Tags: c++, sorting, variadic-templates

To overcome repetition I wrote a templated strict weak ordering predicate to make it easier.

Often when multiple fields are required and/or each of them require different order(ASC/DESC) to sort a container we must create custom comparison predicates which sometimes become spacey or complicated depending on the implementation.

For example(3 fields)

```
if(lhs->IsOnline() == rhs->IsOnline())
{
    if(lhs->GetLowestRankIndex() == rhs->GetLowestRankIndex())
        return lhs->GetName() < rhs->GetName();
    else
        return lhs->GetLowestRankIndex() > rhs->GetLowestRankIndex();
}
else
    return lhs->IsOnline() > rhs->IsOnline();
```

or its less spacey but somewhat complicated equivalent

```
return lhs->IsOnline() > rhs->IsOnline() || (lhs->IsOnline() == rhs->IsOnline()
    && (lhs->GetLowestRankIndex() > rhs->GetLowestRankIndex() || (lhs->GetLowestRankIndex() == rhs->GetLowestRankIndex()
    && lhs->GetName() < rhs->GetName())));
```

> Now I want to ask a question related to variadic templates. As you may have noticed that in my answer I had to add not-used variadic `typename..._` in the base function and an additional `typename... Tail` in the main function because I cannot set tail parameter's type since 2 arguments use the same type and then go on to the next time in the parameter pack. Although it works, I'm not fully content with it as it breaks IDE error detection(at least in VS).
>
> Since 2 arguments have to be sent per Compare type to the function I couldn't find any other way. Is it possible to make the template type deduction expect 2 arguments for one parameter pack?

Comment: `return std::forward_as_tuple(rhs->IsOnline(), rhs->GetLowestRankIndex(), lhs->GetName()) < std::forward_as_tuple(lhs->IsOnline(), lhs->GetLowestRankIndex(), rhs->GetName());`

Comment: @T.C. That's useful only when you want all the fields to be less-then or greater-then

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename Compare, typename..._>
bool SWOPredicate(const typename Compare::first_argument_type &lhs,
    const typename Compare::second_argument_type &rhs)
{
    Compare cmp;
    return cmp(lhs, rhs);
}

template <typename CompareHead, typename... CompareTail, typename... Tail>
bool SWOPredicate(const typename CompareHead::first_argument_type &lhs,
    const typename CompareHead::second_argument_type &rhs,
    const Tail &...tail)
{
    CompareHead cmp;
    return cmp(lhs, rhs) || (lhs == rhs && SWOPredicate<CompareTail..., Tail...>(tail...));
}
```

Usage

```
return SWOPredicate<std::greater<bool>, std::greater<int>, std::less<std::string>>
    (lhs->IsOnline(), rhs->IsOnline(),
    lhs->GetLowestRankIndex(), rhs->GetLowestRankIndex(),
    lhs->GetName(), rhs->GetName());
```